# Toggle cursor hover events on button click

Tags: jquery, cursor, toggle

I'm developing an app that needs to have normal cursor functionality, but when a button is clicked turns the cursor functionality to something else, if that makes sense.

For example, I want to have regular cursor functionality until the user clicks the "Select an element" button, at which point the cursor will start highlighting elements that the user hovers over. I have the whole highlighting functionality covered, but I'm not sure how to toggle the cursor to either start highlight or not highlight.

Another example, I'd have regular cursor functionality until the user clicks the "Draw" button, at which point the cursor would change in to a marquee tool or something and be able to draw on a page. I'm not asking how to draw on the page, but simply *enable* the cursor to draw on the page via toggle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a class with jQuery to the parent container of your hoverable items.

Then you just have to do some CSS on the hover of the object in the who has the new class as parent.

Here an example of the base html:

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="object"></div>
    <div class="object"></div>
    <div class="object"></div>
</div>
<a href='#'>Toggle hover</a>
```

And the jQuery :

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('.section').hasClass('hoverable') ? $('.section').removeClass('hoverable') :         $('.section').addClass('hoverable')
})
```

It check if the hover is active, if not, it make it active, else it remove the class.

Then the css would look like this :

```
.object{
    width: 100px;
    height : 100px;
    margin :40px;
    background-color:blue;
}

.hoverable .object:hover{
    background-color : yellow;
    cursor : pointer;
}
```

I made a fiddle for you : http://jsfiddle.net/7jB3W/

You can do the same for your drawing caneva!

Comment: So you're saying that it's not about changing the functionality of the cursor, it's about adding a class to my highlight elements?

Comment: Well it alway depend of what you want, can I know what happen when you click on an hoverable element? Do it goes to an other page? You can play with the binding of the element where hoverable or not.